# how to preload CosmosDB Database with .net or scripting

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

this seems an easy question, but I didnt find anything in the documentation about it.

I need some "collections" to be pre-loaded with some master data that I need to run the application, is there an easy way to do this? backup/restore?  Create a script?

Whats the recommended approach?

Comment: do you want some specific format of data or random?

Comment: well I have an entity called Roles, with just and id and a Name, I want that preloaded with some Roles for the app

Comment: I am using Shared Collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways,

(i) By writing a Scrip (Master data) using the Cosmosdb SDK

(ii)Populate the data with SQL/JSON and then migrate to [cosmosdb with the tool data migrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data)